# How to save a new-token photo in IOS

Tags: ios, save, uiimagepickercontroller, photo, filepath

I'm now struggling with UIImagePicker.

I've read the document but it seems not to mention how should I save a newly token photo, I mean save it into my own documents in my app.

In fact, there is a "photo" attribute in one of my entity in core data,

so, the "photo" should just be a NSString to save the real photo's file path, right?

But how to save that photo and get its correct file path?

I just know little about NSFilePath or something like that, hope someone to teach me a little bit.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may know how to present the image picker:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[viewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

With the above the viewController implements the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and make sure you implement this function:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)returnedPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

and

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)returnedPicker
```

The first method is called when user has picked a photo.  In this method you get the image using:

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

To write this to a file you can make it a JPEG or a PNG.  If a JPEG you may do this:

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

You just need to set the filename.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFilename.jpg"];
```

To get the image back into a UIImage you do this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename;
if(data != nil)
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's very specific, so the filename is just a NSString? And when I need to get the photo back, I also use the filename as NSString instead of considering photo's file path like /document/resource/ or something like that?

Comment: Added a couple of lines in to explain that - yes it's just an NSString in this case but you need to prefix with the documents directory.